# Django searching based on model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am new in Django .I am trying to write a book shop program. But i have some confusions there.  I have two fields in model  price and bookauthors . i want to write a view for searching the books based on price ranage.. that means if a person select a pricerange between two amounts(price) and a author name(authername) . I want to display the available books based on their selection. How can i write the code for getting these results

my model :

```
  class books(models.Model):
             price = models.IntegerField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
             authorname = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True)
             book=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "auther" is spelt "author"
2. authorname is most likely to be more appropriate as a CharField rather than a TextField
3. especially if you're going to be searching on them
4. are you sure you want to search for an exact price? a price above/below/range seems more likely
5. did you read anything in [the documentation about filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets)?
6. or about [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/)?
7. or about [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/#the-template-layer)?
8. have you considered creating a model just for Authors?
9. is the "book" field perhaps better renamed as "Title"?

Read up on these things, search for answers, and come back with some specific questions after you've made an effort (or finished high school?).

Comment: No i am a highschool student :)